# how to get a cumulative sum on a large dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

I have a large data dataframe (48 x 100). Is there an elegant formula in R that makes you transform this dataframe in to a "custom dataframe"?

```
a = c(2, 3, 5)
b = c(2, 3, 5)
c = c(2, 3, 5)

df <- rbind(a,b,c)
```

Now.. i want cumsum of df so it looks like this.

[image: desired output]

I know its easy to do with a loop.. but is there a function?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also, see `?cumsum`

Comment: yes.. i want cumsum on a large number of columbs. I could just make a loop... but the question is there a more elegant way of doing htis?

Comment: So you want the results in a matrix not a data frame? Please paste the results into a code block not link an image.  Also explain what code you have tried.

Comment: i was not being precise.. dataframe

Comment: The code above creates a matrix not a data frame. See the answer below for the additional step needed. You should either clarify the title of clarify the problem you had.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
a <- c(2, 3, 5)
b <- c(2, 3, 5)
c <- c(2, 3, 5)

df <- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))
df <- cumsum(df)
```

so this dataframe:

```
> df
  X1 X2 X3
a  2  3  5
b  2  3  5
c  2  3  5
```

becomes this:

```
> cumsum(df)
  X1 X2 X3
a  2  3  5
b  4  6 10
c  6  9 15
```

Comment: I didn't know `cumsum` could be used directly on a `data.frame` like this. Very nice!

Comment: @SorenChristensen Make sure you understand that you had created a matrix not a data frame.

Comment: Also @SorenChristensen, you should accept this answer.